# Javascript can't use "i" variable inside of for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, charts

I have a line chart template from CanvasJS. I was trying to use for loop inside that. Loop condition works fine. But when I use `i` variable inside the for, it doesn't work and visual studio doesn't recognize `i`. But instead of using `i`, if I use a number - like 5 or 10 (doesn't matter)- it works fine.

Where is the problem?

```
for(var i=0;i< <%=this.something%>;i++)
{
chart.data[0].addTo("dataPoints", {x: <%=this.historyDate[i]%>, y: <%=this.historyPoint[i]%>})       
});
```

P.S: historyDate and historyPoint are defined in code behind. So i had to use them like that. I'm kind of new to programming. So im sorry if i made a mistake

Comment: You are mixing up a client-side variable with a server-side one.

Comment: What should i do then? I've literally no idea

Comment: try with echo this.historyDate[i] if you are using php

or try to print 'this.historyDate[i]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing server side code with client side code `<%= exp %>` is ASP.NET syntax and it's processed on the server side. `i` is declared in Javascript which will run client side in the browser so the server can't use it

You need to serialize `this.historyDate` as JSON and put in in a javascript variable, if it isn't too big. Or find some other design.

Comment: I tried do define "i" in code behind. It was like this, but didn't work too. <%=this.historyDate[this.i]%>

Comment: @ovuncdeniz4, but then it wouldn't be the same `i` as in javascript

Answer (score 2):

The i variable belongs to javascript, but you are using it inside your template language `<%=this.historyDate[i]%>`. So there i is not defined

Comment: I tried do define "i" in code behind. It was like this, but didn't work too. <%=this.historyDate[this.i]%>